# Best way of looping over a list of dictionaries within a list of dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

If I have this data structure:

```yaml
blahblah:
  - name: firstdict
    touch:
      - file: name1
        type: file
      - file: name2
        type: directory
  - name: seconddict
    touch:
      - file: name3
        type: file
```

How can I loop over this to ensure each `file` exists and is of type `type` whilst handling the event that the `touch` value might not even be present?

I have tried:

```yaml
- name: Blah
  file:
    path: "{{ item.1.file }}"
    state: "{{ item.1.type }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ blahblah }}"
    - touch
```

It seems to work but fails if the `touch` key isn't present in the dictionary. Is there a way to provide a default empty list if `touch` isn't specified?

Comment: Since Ansible is a Python application one speaks of lists, not of arrays.

Comment: One might, I don't ;) It's still an array, whatever it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `loop` syntax instead of the `with_subelements` one.
Not only it is kind of recommended by Ansible, nowadays – see the notes in the [*"Loop"* documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) – it will also force you to use the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#parameter-skip_missing), and with it, discover its [`skip_missing`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#parameter-skip_missing) parameter.

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ blahblah | subelements('touch', skip_missing=True) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
  vars:
    blahblah:
      - name: first dict
        touch:
          - file: name1
          - file: name2
      - name: second dict
        touch:
          - file: name3
      - name: without touch
```

This would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=firstdict) => 
  msg:
  - name: firstdict
    touch:
    - file: name1
      type: file
    - file: name2
      type: directory
  - file: name1
    type: file
ok: [localhost] => (item=firstdict) => 
  msg:
  - name: firstdict
    touch:
    - file: name1
      type: file
    - file: name2
      type: directory
  - file: name2
    type: directory
ok: [localhost] => (item=seconddict) => 
  msg:
  - name: seconddict
    touch:
    - file: name3
      type: file
  - file: name3
    type: file
```

Comment: Thanks, though I think, unless there's confusing wizardry going on, that the vars is missing the 'type' values.